# Controlling workstation-pc with commands issued by Turtlebot

Tags: ros, serial, communication, turtlebot, workstation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I am currently working on an application, where I want to enable/disable signals via ROS workstation's pc serial or USB port.

I currently issue vocal commands to Turtlebot like 'enable Output #1' or 'enable Output #2'.

I want to interpret these commands into signal toggles at the ROS workstation-pc serial port.

Can you please point me to the right direction, since I cannot source any similar applications online.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28878/controlling-workstation-pc-with-commands-issued-by-turtlebot/) by [cg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1801/cg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-03-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1801/cg/) on 2012-03-09**:
I have an Arduino board connected to the ros-workstation-pc usb port. From the other side there is a ros-turtlebot-pc which is able to interpret voice commands. I would like to issue a vocal command to turtlebot-pc, to signal a toggle from ros-turtlebot-pc to the ros-workstation-pc usb port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A vocal command you was looking for has been developed by NICT. Could you check it out on this web( http://rospeex.org/top/ ) ? The tool is called rospeex.

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GT](https://answers.ros.org/users/27012/gt/) on 2016-05-31**:
Hi
I am running Ubuntu 14.04, have installed rospeex voic controller for Turtlebot. When I run this comand from Turtlebot
$ source ~/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/setup.bash
$ rosrun rospeex_audiomonitor audio_monitor_epd
audio_monitor: cannot connect to X server
How to conect to X server?